# Cache Prior .includes in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have three collections – `Company`, `Person`, and `Email` – a company has many people, and a person has many emails

If I do something like

```
company_with_emails_preloaded = Company.includes(people: [:emails]).where(...)
```

I can do `company.people[0].emails` without an additional query / avoiding the n+1 query problem

However, imagine I have a function called `getAllCompanyEmails` that does something like

```
def getAllCompanyEmails(company)
  company.people.includes(:emails).map { |person| person.emails } .flatten
end
```

which calls `.includes` on `company` in the event it hasn't been `.includes`'d already.

When I call `getAllCompanyEmails(company_with_emails_preloaded)`, it runs another join query, ignoring the `.includes` I ran earlier!

My question is: Is there a way to modify `includes` to check if the data has already been included before firing off another query? I think worst case, I can write some kind of `.includes` helper that checks for `.association(:key_name).loaded` for everything, but I feel like something should exist for this within Rails already.

I'm on rails `4.2.11` and ruby `2.6.8` – thanks!

Comment: Can you share details about what goes in `.find(...)`? I believe you're passing an `ApplicationRecord` object instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which isn't going to persist your `includes` because the query has already taken place.

Comment: Sorry the `find` should've been a `where` / bad pseudocode on my part – updating question!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4.2, there isn't a built-in mechanism to check if the association has already been preloaded and avoid the additional query automatically.

In that case, you can manually check if the association is loaded using the `loaded?` method provided by ActiveRecord. Here's an updated version of the `getAllCompanyEmails` method that includes this check:

```
def getAllCompanyEmails(company)
  if company.people.loaded?
    company.people.flat_map(&:emails)
  else
    company.people.includes(:emails).flat_map(&:emails)
  end
end
```

In this updated implementation, if the people association of the company is already loaded, it directly retrieves the emails from the preloaded data. Otherwise, it performs the includes query to load the associated emails and then retrieves them.

By using `flat_map(&:emails)`, we avoid the need to call flatten on the resulting array.

Please note that this approach is specific to Rails 4.2, as newer versions of Rails provide better handling of preloading associations.

Comment: Hey @shaam this doesn't seem to be working for me

If I do `company_with_emails_preloaded = Company.includes(people: [:emails]).where(...)` I see the SQL calls for company & people & emails logged, as usual/expected

Then, when I call the method with `.references` in `getAllCompanyEmails`, I see a new SQL query called, which runs the join query (but doesn't leverage that initial `.includes` on `company_with_emails_preloaded`, which means I'm still double-querying)